# How to Use Ado.net Model in Helper Class in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have a folder

```
 Helper

 1. Class (SessionManagement.cs)
```

I have Model.edmx at root.

How can I use Model in my SessionManagement Class

I want it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NGO_MS.Model; // Error is The type or name space Model does not exist
using NGO_MS.Controls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.UI;
using NSLogger;
using NGO_MS.DAL;
using System.Configuration;
```

My question is how can i use it with using ? I am beginer Kindly guide me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the below answer should help you.  If the SessionManagement and Model.edmx are in the same project then it should just work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a method in your SessionManangement class paste the following code.

```
using (Model ctx = new Model()){

}
```

Comment: I was missing Model reference :) Fixed it :D

Comment: Great.  Visual Studio should have tried to resolve the namespace for you.